# Mocking service when testing controller in Karma for angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing

I am working on the Single Page Application with AngularJS project for the Treehouse Full Stack JavaScript TechDegree and I am trying to do unit tests on the controllers.  To test the controllers that make api calls to the dataService I have to mock the dataService and I can not figure out how to do this correctly.  I have read article after article on unit testing angular and I am so lost that I have no idea what to do next.

controllers.js:

```
(function() {
  'use strict';
  angular.module('app')
  .controller('RecipesController', function(dataService,$location) {
    const vm = this;

    vm.init = () => {
      vm.hidden = true;
      dataService.getAllRecipes(function(response) {
        vm.recipes = response.data;
        vm.getCategories(response.data);
      });
    }

    vm.selectCategory = (category) => {
      if (category === null) {
        vm.init();
      } else {
        dataService.getCategory(category,function(response) {
          vm.recipes = response.data;
        });
      }
    };

    vm.getCategories = (data) => {
      let categories = new Set();
      for (let item of data) {
        categories.add(item.category);
      }
      vm.categories = Array.from(categories);
    };

    vm.addRecipe = () => {
      $location.path('/add');
    }

    vm.deleteRecipe = (recipe,$index) => {
      vm.toDelete = recipe.name;
      vm.hidden = false;
      vm.deleteIt = () => {
        vm.hidden = true;
        dataService.deleteRecipe(recipe._id,function(response) {
          vm.init();
        });
      }
    }

    vm.init();
  })
  .controller('RecipeDetailController', function($scope,dataService,$location) {
    const vm = this;
    const init = () => {
      const path = $location.path();
      if (path.includes("edit")) {
        let id = path.slice(6);
        dataService.getID(id,function(response) {
          vm.recipe = response.data;
          vm.title = response.data.name;
          vm.editCategory = response.data.category;
        });
      } else if (path.includes("add")) {
        vm.recipe = {
          name: "",
          description: "",
          category: "",
          prepTime: 0,
          cookTime: 0,
          ingredients: [
            {
              foodItem: "",
              condition: "",
              amount: ""
            }
          ],
          steps: [
            {
              description: ""
            }
          ]
        }
        vm.title = 'Add New Recipe.'
      }

      dataService.getAllCategories(function (response) {
        vm.categories = response.data;
        let index = response.data.findIndex(item => item.name === $scope.editCategory);
        if (index === -1) {
          vm.initial = {"name": "Choose a Category"};
        } else {
          vm.initial = $scope.categories[index];
        }
      });

      dataService.getAllFoodItems(function (response) {
        vm.foods = response.data;
      });
    }

    vm.addItem = (item) => {
      if (item === 'ingredient') {
        vm.recipe.ingredients.push({amount: "amount", condition: "condition", foodItem: ""});
      } else if (item === 'step') {
        vm.recipe.steps.push({description: "description"});
      }
    };

    vm.deleteItem = (item,$index) => {
      if (item === 'ingredient') {
        vm.recipe.ingredients.splice($index,1);
      } else if (item === 'step') {
        vm.recipe.steps.splice($index,1);
      }

    }

    vm.saveChanges = (recipe) => {

      vm.errors = [];

      const buildErrorArray = (errorArray) => {
        for (let item of errorArray) {
          vm.errors.push(item.userMessage);
        }
      }

      const collectErrors = (response) => {
        if (response.data.errors.category) { buildErrorArray(response.data.errors.category) }
        if (response.data.errors.ingredients) { buildErrorArray(response.data.errors.ingredients) }
        if (response.data.errors.name) { buildErrorArray(response.data.errors.name) }
        if (response.data.errors.steps) { buildErrorArray(response.data.errors.steps) }
      }

      if (recipe._id) {
        dataService.updateID(recipe,function(response) {
          $location.path('/');
          }, function(response) {
            collectErrors(response)
        });
      } else {
        dataService.addRecipe(recipe,function(response) {
          $location.path('/');
          }, function(response) {
            collectErrors(response)
        });
      }

    }

    vm.cancelChanges = () => {
      $location.path('/');
    }

    init();

  });
}());
```

services.js:

```
(function() {
  'use strict';
  angular.module('app')
  .service('dataService', function($http,errors,httpErrors) {

    this.getAllRecipes = function (callback) {
      $http.get('http://localhost:5000/api/recipes')
      .then(callback,httpErrors.display('HTTP Error'))
      .catch(errors.catch());
    };

    this.getAllCategories = function (callback) {
      $http.get('http://localhost:5000/api/categories')
      .then(callback,httpErrors.display('HTTP Error'))
      .catch(errors.catch());
    };

    this.getAllFoodItems = function (callback) {
      $http.get('http://localhost:5000/api/fooditems')
      .then(callback,httpErrors.display('HTTP Error'))
      .catch(errors.catch());
    };

    this.getCategory = function(category,callback) {
      $http.get('http://localhost:5000/api/recipes?category=' + category)
      .then(callback,httpErrors.display('HTTP Error'))
      .catch(errors.catch());
    };

    this.getID = function (id,callback) {
      $http.get('http://localhost:5000/api/recipes/' + id)
      .then(callback,httpErrors.display('HTTP Error'))
      .catch(errors.catch());
    };

    this.updateID = function (data,success,error) {
      $http.put('http://localhost:5000/api/recipes/' + data._id, data)
      .then(success,error).catch(errors.catch());
    };

    this.addRecipe = function (data,success,error) {
      $http.post('http://localhost:5000/api/recipes', data)
      .then(success,error).catch(errors.catch());
    };

    this.deleteRecipe = function (id,callback) {
      $http.delete('http://localhost:5000/api/recipes/' + id)
      .then(callback,httpErrors.display('HTTP Error'))
      .catch(errors.catch());
    };

  });
}());
```

controllersSpec.js:

```
describe("Unit Testing Controllers", function() {

  beforeEach(angular.mock.module('app'));

  let $scope;
  let getAllRecipesMock;

  beforeEach(inject(function(_$controller_,_$rootScope_,$q) {
    $controller = _$controller_;
    $scope = _$rootScope_.$new();

    getAllRecipesMock = {
      getAllRecipes: function() {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        deferred.resolve([{name: "recipename"}]);
        return deferred.promise;
      }            
    }
  }));

  it('has a test to test that tests are testing', function() {
    expect(2 + 2).toEqual(4);
  });

  it('should have a RecipesController', function() {
    const controller = $controller('RecipesController',{$scope:$scope});
    expect(controller).toBeDefined();
  });

  it('should have a RecipeDetailController', function() {
    const controller = $controller('RecipeDetailController',{$scope:$scope});
    expect(controller).toBeDefined();
  });

  it('should call the getAllRecipes service and return response', inject(function() {
    const controller = $controller('RecipesController',{$scope:$scope,dataService:getAllRecipesMock});
    $scope.$digest();
    expect(controller.recipes).toBe([{name: "recipename"}]);
  }));

  it('should remove duplicate categories', function() {
    const controller = $controller('RecipesController',{$scope:$scope});
    let data = [{'category':'dog'},{'category':'cat'},{'category':'horse'},{'category':'dog'},{'category':'cow'}];
    controller.getCategories(data);
    expect(controller.categories).toEqual(['dog','cat','horse','cow']);
  });

  it('should take you to the /add route when the addRecipe method is called', inject(function($location) {
    const controller = $controller('RecipesController',{$scope:$scope});
    controller.addRecipe();
    expect($location.path()).toEqual('/add');
  }));

});
```

This is the result I get when I run the tests:

```
 Unit Testing Controllers
    √has a test to test that tests are testing
    √should have a RecipesController
    √should have a RecipeDetailController
    ×should call the getAllRecipes service and return response
        Expected undefined to be [ Object({ name: 'recipename' }) ].
            at Object.<anonymous> (test/controllersSpec.js:38:32)
            at Object.invoke (node_modules/angular/angular.js:4839:19)
            at Object.WorkFn (node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:3155:20)

    √should remove duplicate categories
    √should take you to the /add route when the addRecipe method is called

Chrome 55.0.2883 (Windows 10 0.0.0): Executed 6 of 6 (1 FAILED) (0.235 secs / 0.084 secs)
TOTAL: 1 FAILED, 5 SUCCESS


1) should call the getAllRecipes service and return response
     Unit Testing Controllers
     Expected undefined to be [ Object({ name: 'recipename' }) ].
    at Object.<anonymous> (test/controllersSpec.js:38:32)
    at Object.invoke (node_modules/angular/angular.js:4839:19)
    at Object.WorkFn (node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:3155:20)
```

**EDIT**

I decided to change the service to return a promise instead of a callback:

```
this.getAllRecipes = function () {
     return $http.get('http://localhost:5000/api/recipes');
    };
```

Then I changed the corresponding function in the controller:

```
vm.init = () => {
      vm.hidden = true;
      let allRecipes = dataService.getAllRecipes();
      allRecipes.then(function(response) {
        vm.recipes = response.data;
        vm.getCategories(response.data);
      },httpErrors.display('HTTP Error'))
      .catch(errors.catch());
    }
```

but I'm still getting

`Expected undefined to be [ Object({ name: 'recipename' }) ].`

Am I not implementing the promise correctly?  Is there still something in my test that I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are currently mixing callbacks and promises.

The method `getAllRecipes` in the real service implementation takes a callback as an argument and executes it when the internal ajax call is done. The consumer of the method has no idea that the implementation uses promises internally.

The mock implementation of `getAllRecipes` however does not take or use a callback function but instead returns a promise.

You have in your controller:

```
dataService.getAllRecipes(function(response) {

  vm.recipes = response.data;
  vm.getCategories(response.data);
});
```

But with the mock implementation you would need:

```
dataService.getAllRecipes(function(response) {

  vm.recipes = response.data;
  vm.getCategories(response.data);
}).then(function (response) {

  // Code
});
```

With your current implementation of `getAllRecipes` your mock could look like this:

```
getAllRecipesMock = {
  getAllRecipes: function(callback) {

    var response = {
      data: [{
        name: "recipename"
      }]
    };

    callback(response);
  }
};
```

Also note that unless you want to compare for reference equality, use `toEqual` instead of `toBe`:

```
expect(controller.recipes).toEqual([{
  name: "recipename"
}]);
```

**Demo**: http://plnkr.co/edit/5BQBt4tTxohXEN0Drq3f?p=preview

An alternative is to change the service implementation to return a promise instead of using callbacks.

Comment: I updated the question with some changes but I'm still getting the undefined error.

Comment: @SmellydogCoding Please don't update and change the question after it has been answered and solved :) I don't mind helping though. Seems to work: http://plnkr.co/edit/UnloQivYZmOJ3WgZanye?p=preview

Comment: Thank you for all of your help!  I didn't mean to be rude by changing the question after you answered it.  After doing some reading about JavaScript promises, I decided to take your advice and change the service implementation to return a promise instead of a callback because that made more sense to me.  I'm still trying to wrap my brain around why the solution works, and around mocking services in general.  I'm glad it did work though.  Thanks again.

Comment: @SmellydogCoding It's no problem, was just a friendly advice :) I don't mind helping if you need more help. I have my e-mail in my profile for a reason :)